# python setup.py egg_info gcc error installing cassandra python

Tags: python, gcc

For some reason, the specific version that I need to install manually cannot be accessed directly:

> ```
>   rpm -i ftp://195.220.108.108/linux/centos/7.1.1503/updates/x86_64/Packages/python-2.7.5-18.el7_1.1.x86_64.rpm
> ```

So tried a brand new installation of python, then tried updating and installing setup tools

> ```
> yum -y update
> yum -y install python-pip
> pip install -U pip
> pip install -U setuptools
> pip install cassandra-driver
> yum install patch
> ```

then tried

> ```
>   wget https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py
>   python ez_setup.py
>   pip install cassandra-driver
> ```

Full stacktrace

```
[root@d8174406546b cassandradump]# pip install cassandra-driver
Collecting cassandra-driver
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:315: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject
 Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validat
ion failures. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
  SNIMissingWarning
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:120: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. Thi
s prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/e
n/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Using cached cassandra-driver-3.0.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    warning: no files found matching '*.pyx' under directory 'Cython/Debugger/Tests'
    warning: no files found matching '*.pxd' under directory 'Cython/Debugger/Tests'
    warning: no files found matching '*.h' under directory 'Cython/Debugger/Tests'
    warning: no files found matching '*.pxd' under directory 'Cython/Utility'
    unable to execute gcc: No such file or directory
    Unable to find pgen, not compiling formal grammar.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-cP9FYQ/cassandra-driver/setup.py", line 375, in <module>
        run_setup(None)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-cP9FYQ/cassandra-driver/setup.py", line 373, in run_setup
        **kw)
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 112, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 269, in __init__
        self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 313, in fetch_build_eggs
        replace_conflicting=True,
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 827, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1072, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1084, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 380, in fetch_build_egg
        return cmd.easy_install(req)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 640, in easy_install
        return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 670, in install_item
        dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 853, in install_eggs
        return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1081, in build_and_install
        self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1069, in run_setup
        raise DistutilsError("Setup script exited with %s" % (v.args[0],))
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-cP9FYQ/cassandra-driver
```

Answer (score 2):

Typed enter too early, missed gcc library and got carried away by similar posts.

```
/tmp/easy_install-N19BCp/Cython-0.23.4/Cython/Plex/Scanners.c:4:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include "Python.h"
                    ^
compilation terminated.
Unable to find pgen, not compiling formal grammar.
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Then python-devel solved the problem.

```
install yum install python-devel
```

Answer (score 0):

I am working inside docker so prefixed the 'RUN'. On real systems, you will need to use sudo in place of RUN. Sometimes, the pip is tool old. In my case it was 7.x so I also upgraded it. cython depends on python-devel

```
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN yum -y install python-devel
RUN pip install cython
```